# How should Apache IoTDB both merge and page data values of different time periods in multiple devices?

Tags: database, merge, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am still a newbie to Apache IoTDB and I have a question when reading the official user guide ---

Can Apache IoTDB generate merging and paging the data result of different time periods from multiple physical quantities of multiple devices?

In the official guide, it seems like only the instructions of simply merging data are clear, but how can the data also be paged in certain settings?

Any statement that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check the data of the first time series data in Apache IoTDB, using `last` is a good choice.

I checked using `limit` on the official guide. The syntax can be supported to use, but the may not be very convenient for your condition.